# Menu home page background color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a NavigationPage.TitleView control on my home page but it looks like there is a problem filling the whole title section. The HamburgerMenu icon is coming from the menupage.xaml and that background color is not getting set?

> Do I need to get a new icon with that background Color I need?

homepage.xaml

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#22335c">
        <Label Text="N" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#22335c" TextColor="White"  />
        <Image Source=""  Aspect="AspectFit"  BackgroundColor="#22335c" />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Menupage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MenuPage"
             xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
             xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ReimbursementApp.Model"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:ReimbursementApp.Pages"
             Title="Menu"  Icon="HamburgerMenu.png" BackgroundColor="Black">
```

[image: Color Problem with menu icon]

Comment: does the PNG have a transparent background?

Comment: Yes HamburgerMenu.png has a transparent background.

Comment: Have you tried setting setting the `BarBackgroundColor` property of your `NavigaitonPage`?

Comment: @G.hakim is that in the NavigationPage.TitleView?

Comment: Where are you defining your `NavigationPage`

Comment: I dont have a object NavigationPage just NavigationPage.TitleView?

Comment: @G.hakim Any else I need to do to get this working?

Comment: 'Well if you have a NavigationPage object you can use that to set its BarBackgroundColor property to do this

Comment: @G.hakim I have it in the app page  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

Comment: Okay do one thing try this `var navPage=new NavigationPage(new MainPage());` then do this `navPage.BarBackgroundColor=yourColor` and then assign it as main page `MainPage=navPage;`

Comment: @G.hakim you want to do a webex?

Comment: Sure we can do that i don't mind email me @ hakimgulamali88@gmail.com